# SQL Order ordinal repeat

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have order by zoneId on my sql

```
ZoneID     | Description | 
1          | something   |    
1          | something   | 
1          | something   |             
2          | something   | 
2          | something   |           
2          | something   |     
3          | something   |
3          | something   |
3          | something   |
```

But I'd like to order it like this, it's possible

```
ZoneID     | Description  | 
1          | something    |     
2          | something    | 
3          | something    |
1          | something    |   
2          | something    |          
3          | something    |
1          | something    |   
2          | something    |           
3          | something    |
```

Answer (score 1):

In sql server you can use [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select ZoneId, Description
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by ZoneId order by (select 1)), ZoneId
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ATQBA77275

returns:

```
+--------+-------------+
| ZoneId | Description |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 | something   |
|      2 | something   |
|      3 | something   |
|      1 | something   |
|      2 | something   |
|      3 | something   |
|      1 | something   |
|      2 | something   |
|      3 | something   |
+--------+-------------+
```

---

To use it in a view (where you can not `order by` without `top`), just add a column with the `row_number()`:

```
create view dbo.with_rownumber as
select 
    ZoneId
  , Description
  , rn = row_number() over (partition by ZoneId order by (select 1))
from t;

go
select ZoneId, Description
from dbo.with_rownumber
order by rn, ZoneId
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can I use row_number on an SQL view ?, I think SQL views can't perform row_number

Comment: @tonydeleon Updated my answer to include how to use `row_number()` inside a view and `order by` outside the view.

Comment: Thanks you very much  @SqlZim